# VS Code: Analyzing in the background

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I start a python project in vs code (with the microsoft python extension) it starts "Analyzing in the background" and python keep crashing. It also uses a ton of memory.[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or is it supposed to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem after updating VS Code, doesn't crash but makes VS Code very slow and takes up all memory.

Comment: Please do help provide information at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server to help debug why you're having your issue; we are trying to squash these bugs before making the language server the default experience.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to have fixed it for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4990#issuecomment-477628947

> You can disable the new Python Language Server by opening settings in VSCode (Ctrl+, ) and set "python.jediEnabled": true. Then reload the window and/or restart VSCode.

Comment: This does help but it looses all the advanced functionality of the intellisense.

Comment: At least VS Code is usable. Intellisense can be enabled after its problems are solved.

Comment: Finally, it's stable for me. It takes about 2-3 minutes in the beginning to analyze files, but it doesn't hang or crash vscode.

Comment: I had to click download pylint after activating jedi then it told me to reload window to activate intelisense.python what i did, unfortunately i was stuck in a loop of reloading window and activating jedi/intelisence back and forth. Saving `"python.jediEnabled":false` helped to get out of the loop and after that now intelisense Background Analysis runs through smooth and works. Maybe somebody can try to solely install pylint to solve the problem in one step?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue; the only solution that worked for me was to open `settings.json` (ctrl + Shift + P) and change

```
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft"
```

to

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

Then one gets a pop-up that asks whether one wants to reload the window which one should confirm by pressing "OK".

Then everything works normally again (IntelliJ, autocomplete etc).

As @Vasco pointed out in the comments `Microsoft` is no longer supported as explained in [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/2158#issuecomment-878589332).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and I also just noticed that they stopped supporting the "Microsoft" version, see: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/2158#issuecomment-878589332

Comment: @Vasco: Thanks, I updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

High memory usage： https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/issues/832
Jedi is an autocompletion tool for Python that can be used in IDEs/editors. Jedi works. Jedi is fast. It understands all of the basic Python syntax elements including many builtin functions. So you can switch Jedi instead of Python Language Server.

Process:

1. set "python.jediEnabled": true
2. disable the Visual Studio IntelliCode plugin
3. delete the .vscode directory

Comment: I don't think you need steps 2 and 3. Just make sure that `python.jediEnabled: true` in `settings.json`, which is inside the `.vscode` directory.

Answer (score 4):

Can solve this by either disabling the extension as suggested in previous answers, or excluding large directories (e.g. containing data) from its search path, by adding to your workspace settings an `python.workspaceSymbols.exclusionPatterns` key, like so:

settings.json:

```json
{
    "python.workspaceSymbols.exclusionPatterns": [
        "**/site-packages/**",
        "your_pattern_or_directory_to_exclude"
    ]
}
```

See also the [vscode extension docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference).

Comment: In my case I was including python virtual environment folder, but because I excluded it in the `.gitignore` file it didn't show up in the folder browser, so I had no idea what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings > **TYPE** "python.language server"

If set to **'Microsoft'** change your language server to **'Pylance'**

```
Python: Language Server
Define Type of the Language Server
SELECT: Pylance
```

Reload your Visual Studio Code
Try importing your libraries causing the issues again:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```